# Need an expression to use in an azure logic app in-order to fetch an element of a JSON

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I have a JSON Content in my Logic App. I need to fetch only a particular element (value of commitId) from the JSON and not all attributes. Can you please help me to write an appropriate expression !

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "value": [
    {
      "commitId": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
      "author": {
        "name": "mahesh",
        "email": "mahesh@xyz.com",
        "date": "2020-03-27T09:43:03Z"
      },
      "committer": {
        "name": "mahesh",
        "email": "mahesh@xyz.com",
        "date": "2020-03-27T09:43:03Z"
      },
      "comment": "Added task markdown file.",
      "changeCounts": {
        "Add": 1,
        "Edit": 0,
        "Delete": 0
      },
      "changes": [
        {
          "sourceServerItem": "/Books",
          "changeType": "edit"
        }
      ],
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/company/aaaabbbbbbb/_apis/git/repositories/ccccddddd/commits/eeeeeefffff",
      "remoteUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/company/DataEngineering/_git/Test/commit/aaabbbbccccdddd"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse your json data and then please refer to the expression below:
[image]

The whole expression in the screenshot above is:

```
body('Parse_JSON')?['value'][0]?['commitId']
```

Then we can get the value of `commitId` after running it.
[image]

Comment: Thank You So Much. This Solved my problem.